# how to open the file with path name?

Tags: python, filehandler

I am trying to open the file using a path instead of file name I used `glob.glob` option to go and search in the path for an input file. Now I got struck with opening that. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import glob
a = (glob.glob("*/file.txt"))
with open (a, 'r') as f:
```

Trying to read the file.txt and I am getting error in line3. Any help would be appreciated.

Error: TypeError: expacted str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Answer (score 1):

`glob.glob` returns a list of file paths.  You will need to access one of the paths in the list, or iterate over them.

```
import glob

a = glob.glob("*/file.txt")
with open(a[0], 'r') as f:
    text= f.read()
```

Comment: It is still giving me error saying : (result, consumed) = sel._buffer_decode(data, self.error, final) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf - 8' code can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte.

Comment: @user7090 Sounds like you might need to open the file as binary format (`'rb'` instead of `'r'`).

Comment: @alaniwi Is it possible to open the file in read format instead of reading in binary format

Answer (score 0):

`glob.glob()` returns a list. You need to loop through it, opening each file.

```
import glob

for filename in glob.glob("*/file.txt"):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        ...
```

Comment: I am facing the same error as mentioned in the above comment

Comment: That's completely unrelated. It's not a plain text file.

Comment: Or you need to specify the encoding

Comment: Will it read the data in the file.txt if we use glob.glob() option

Comment: How you get the filename has nothing to do with how you read the file.

Comment: Well, Actually I am trying to search the directories and read the text in the file.txt file

Comment: That's obvious. I just mean that once you have a filename, it doesn't matter where it came from when you try to read the file.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the filename, it's about the contents of the file. It's not valid UTF-8 data.

Comment: How can we resolve this error "Error: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list"

Comment: That's what my answer fixes.